# "Unauthorized" - While making a call to SOAP api C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, soap

While using the below code to make a call to the SOAP, I am getting the "Unauthorized" as a response.

```
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Credentials = credentials;

   try
   {
       WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
       using(Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
       {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
       }
   }
   catch(WebException Ex)
   {
        WebResponse errorResponse = Ex.Response;
        using(Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
            string errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        throw;
    }
```

Can you please correct me where I am wrong?

**I am getting the error :- "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."**

Comment: @codran can you please guide me how to use it?

Comment: are you sure service has n/w authorisation, It can be normal header also something like request.Headers.Add("Username", "XXXX")
request.Headers.Add("PAssword", "yyyy")

Comment: @abhi - I have tried that as well, but its also not working

Comment: Is this a soap API you created? If not then you need to know the proper documentation on how to pass credentials for authorization purposes. There could be a token header somewhere. Varies on the API being targeted.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
             HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
            string authInfo = "username" + ":" + "Password";
            authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));

            request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + authInfo;
            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

           using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
               StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

Comment: you can pass your credentials in the header with basic authentication and it should work fine

Comment: Sorry mate, but still getting the same error

The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Comment: are you sure you are using the correct credentials? because I am currently running the same code for one of my services and it went through properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error. It is a warning about your credential. You should send legal user credential to get a response to your end-point. Please check-out this;

```
NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential{
Username=//fill your username,
Password=//fill your password but be carefull, is it hashed or not?
};
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Credentials = credentials;

   try
   {
       WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
       using(Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
       {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
       }
   }
   catch(WebException Ex)
   {
        WebResponse errorResponse = Ex.Response;
        using(Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
            string errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        throw;
    }
```